# NGINX - redirect userdir to another domain

Tags: nginx, virtualhost, redirect, mod-userdir

I had an apache virtualhost config that redirects "http://host.domain.com/~userdir" to another host:

> RewriteRule   ^/~(.+)  [http://anotherhost.domain.com/~$1](http://anotherhost.domain.com/%7E$1)  [R,L]

But I'm having trouble to migrate this config to Nginx. Anyone could help me please?

Comment: Questions seeking installation, configuration or diagnostic help must include the desired end state, the specific problem or error, sufficient information about the configuration and environment to reproduce it, and attempted solutions. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers and are unlikely to get good answers

Comment: Welcome to ServerFault. What have you tried so far?